# E: unable to locate package airmon-ng

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, chrome-book, airmon-ng

I've been using chromebook with Chrome OS and I installed Ubuntu with this tutorial    ( https://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343 ), and now when I want to install airmon-ng it gave me this

> E: unable to locate package airmon-ng

How to solve this ?

Comment: edit your question and explain what you tried to produce the error message shown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your APT database and then install it.
Let run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install aircrack-ng
```

After that, you will have airmon-ng.

Comment: The airmon-ng tool is inside aircrack-ng package, so you need to install aircrack-ng to get airmon-ng.

Comment: after that it gaves please install lspci from your distros package manager. Then i run **apt-get update && apt-get install pciutils**, after that it gave your kernel has module supports but you dont have installed modprobe, modinfo (typically from kmod); warring : driver detection without modinfo may yield inaccurate results. ; ls : asnnot access /sys/ class/ ieee80211/ no such file or directory.